# Special characters are weird using font-face

Tags: font-face

I'm using font-face to pick up my fonts I use on my website. The Swedish characters ÅÄÖ åäö does exist in the font set, but it still shows up weird.

What might be the problem? Here's the code I use to get the font files.

```
font-family: 'LinotypeAroma';
        src: url('../fonts/linotype_aroma_light_sc.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/linotype_aroma_light_sc.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../fonts/linotype_aroma_light_sc.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/linotype_aroma_light_sc.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../fonts/linotype_aroma_light_sc.svg#linotype_aroma_light_sc') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
```

Comment: Make sure to use `UTF-8` encoding. Add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` after the start tag `<head>` to ensure that the browser uses the correct encoding.